# Calling a T Method and converting results to string C#

Tags: c#, generics, .net-5

I have the following generic method:

```
        public T GetUserPreference<T>(string keyName, string programName)
        {
            string json = preferencesRepository.GetUserPreference(keyName, programName);
            if (json != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogError(ex, nameof(GetUserPreference));
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }
```

Here is the code for my `GetUserPreference` method:

```
        public string GetUserPreference(string key, string programName)
        {
            string query = { Retrieving data from a varbinary field in SQL }
            List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>
            {
                new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = GlobalUserName },
                new SqlParameter("@ProgramName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = programName },
                new SqlParameter("@KeyName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = key }
            };
            try
            {
                object preferenceResult = Data.ExecuteScalar(query, SqlServerConnectionString, sqlParams.ToArray());
                return preferenceResult == null ? null : Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])preferenceResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I tried calling it like this:
`string preference = preferencesService.GetUserPreference(key, programName);`

But I get the following error:

> The type arguments for method 'PreferencesService.GetUserPreference(string, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The Method it is being called from is  as follows:

```
        [ApiVersion("1.0")]
        [HttpGet("v{version:apiVersion}/Preferences", Name = "Get User Preference")]
        public IActionResult Get(string key, string programName)
        {
            string preference = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<T>(key, programName);
            if (preference == null)
            {
                return new NoContentResult();
            }
            return Content(preference);
        }
```

How do I call this generic method ?

Comment: please add some code to describe the signature of `preferencesRepository.GetUserPreference`

Comment: Sure, I will add shortly

Comment: Im not sure of why did u write "T" in the type param <T>? T for itself is not a type. in functions its like a generic type to be filled by the caller. you should call this method in the controller with some type like "object" or whatever type is needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the type argument of a generic method by adding it like in the definition:

```
string preference = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<TheActualTypeYouKnowItIs>(key, programName);
```

C# compiler can't guess it in this context, basically since it would return string for any type argument.

Comment: I initially tried that, but I get an error that the type of namespace name 'T' could not be found. I edited my question to show where this is being called from, perhaps it may give more context ? In addition to this, it wants to install a package NPOI, which I don't recognize, no not sure if this should really be installed ?

Comment: The error comes from the fact that you should tell the compiler which `T` you want to call it with. `preferencesService.GetUserPreference<TheTypeYouWant>`

Comment: The `GetUserPreference<T>` is defined in my PreferencesService, which is being called from my APIcontroller. The GetUserPreference method(Im noticing now they are called the same), is called in my repository.

Comment: Thanks @Pac0 - I ended up doing this: `string preference = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<string>(key, programName);` So what you say, makes sense! Thanks! Which removed the error, seems there is now a deeper issue aswell, where I am using the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>`.

Comment: Thanks Pac0, you led me to making the change I needed to remove the error! Learnt something new in the process now as well...Even though its really not as complicated as I thought it was

Comment: glad to help, this kind of "headaches" will help you have a better mental vision of what is a generic class and/or method and how the C# compiler sees them.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `T` (or any type filler) if you are in Generic context (a Generic method or class).

For example, your first method

```cs
public T GetUserPreference<T>(string keyName, string programName)
```

However, in a non-generic caller, you have to specify the type you want to invoke the generic method with. So

```cs
string preference = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<T>(key, programName); 
//Wrong in non generic context
```

Here you should use and actual type instead of T.

Now, as per the implementation you have for `GetUserPreference<T>`, the `T` is used to determine the type to be used for deserializing. So you should use the type you expect your result to be in.

Example,

```cs
string preference = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<string>(key, programName);
```

Comment: Thanks! Pac0 actually gave me the answer that made me do exactly what you provided. Thanks though. Appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

You have to define T type, since this type is using to deserialize JsonSerializer.Deserialize< T >(json). If for some reasons you don't know type, you can use object as type, but basically it will be just parsed. And  you have a bug  return type should be T, not string

```
var preference  = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<object>(key, programName);
```

or if you really expecting string it should be

```
var preference  = preferencesService.GetUserPreference<string>(key, programName);
```

Comment: `string preference = default(object);` won't compile (`default(T)` is one of the things the function can return)

Comment: @BenVoigt It is a bug in a OP post.  It should  expect T , not a string. And by they way return default(T);  when T is object it returns null

Comment: I don't think `string` is an accident or a bug.  The title of the question says "converting results to string".